# Fixpoint computation via iterated function application

Tags: set-theory

Let $S$ be an (infinite) set. Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal such that $|S| < \kappa$.

Consider a monotone function $f\colon \mathcal{P}(S)\to\mathcal{P}(S)$. It is well-known that $f$ has a least fixpoint. Moreover, if we define $f^0 := \emptyset$, $f^{\alpha+1} := f(f^\alpha)$, and $f^\lambda := \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} f^\alpha$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$, one can show that there exists an ordinal $\beta < \kappa$ such that $\mathrm{lfp}\,f = f^\beta$. Let $\beta_f$ denote the least such ordinal.

Now consider a family $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ of monotone functions (where $I$ is some index set).

Clearly, $\sup_{i\in I} \beta_{f_i} \leq \kappa$.

Are there non-trivial conditions on $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ that imply $\sup_{i\in I} \beta_{f_i} < \kappa$?

Comment: It seems to me that in general $\beta_f$ can be an arbitarily large member of $\kappa$ . So if $|I|\geq $cf$(\kappa)$ we would need restrictions on the $f_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that regardless of $f$, $\beta_f$ is $<\vert S\vert^+$. So if $\kappa>\vert S\vert^+$, then regardless of our collection we'll have $\sup\beta_{f_i}\le \vert S\vert^+<\kappa$.

So what if $\kappa=\vert S\vert^+$?

Well, since successor cardinals are regular, this is again trivial if we have $\vert I\vert<\kappa$.

So what if $\kappa=\vert I\vert$? (From now on identify $I$ and $\kappa$.)

Now we have a problem. For $\alpha<\kappa^+$ let $E_\alpha$ be a well-ordering (think enumeration) of $\kappa$ of ordertype at least $\alpha$. Let $<_\alpha$ be the associated ordering on $\kappa$, let $\downarrow_\alpha(\beta)=\{\gamma: \gamma\le_\alpha\beta\}$ be the initial segment below $\beta$, and let $f_\alpha$ be the smallest set of the form $\downarrow_\alpha(\beta)$ properly containing $X$ (or $S$, if $X=S$). Then $\beta_{f_\alpha}\ge\alpha$ (exercise). This means that the sup of the $\beta_{f_\alpha}$s is $\kappa$ itself.

It's not clear to me what nice properties these $f_\alpha$s don't have, so at present I don't know any interesting conditions which yield the desired property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your observations are correct, of course. The counterexample could perhaps be spelled out more carefully: note that $f_\alpha$ should be a function from $\mathcal{P}(S)$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)$.